# Does Azure Storage Analytics stop logging in $logs container after reaching the 20TB limit?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

As mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/operational-security#azure-storage-analytics

Does Azure Storage Analytics stop logging in `$logs` container after reaching the 20TB limit? Or does it automatically delete the older log files to make space for the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to **Sumarigo-MSFT** on Azure forums for the answer

By default, Storage Analytics will not delete any logging or metrics data. Blobs and table entities will continue to be written until the shared 20 TiB limit is reached. **Once the 20 TiB limit is reached, Storage Analytics will stop writing new data and will not resume until free space is available.** This 20 TiB limit is independent of the total limit for your storage account. For more information on storage account limits, see Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets.

There are two ways to delete Storage Analytics data: by manually making deletion requests or by setting a data retention policy. Manual requests to delete Storage Analytics data are billable, but delete requests resulting from a retention policy are not billable.

Note: To avoid unnecessary charges, set a retention policy for logging and metrics

You can configure two data retention policies: one for logging and one for metrics. When enabled for both, Storage Analytics will delete logs and table entries older than the specified number of days. The maximum retention period is 365 days (1 year)..

Note: If you disable Storage Analytics for a storage service but a data retention policy is enabled, your old data will continue to get deleted. To avoid accidental data loss, ensure that you configure your data retention policy when enabling and disabling Storage Analytics.

Source: [Does Storage Analytics stop logging in $logs after reaching the 20TB limit?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/86096/does-storage-analytics-stop-logging-in-logs-after.html)